# Parsing "I was in the soup now good."

Tags: parsing

I came across this sentence in [an article by John McPhee](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2021/04/19/tabula-rasa-volume-two) but I'm unable to parse it. Could you please help me parse it?

The sentence reads

> By the end of 1945, I had passed the point of no return. **I was in the soup now good.**

Basically, I can't figure out what **good** is doing there.

Comment: If you can add the link to the article (as I've done), it can help us understand the full context.

Comment: I guess, this could misleadingly be parsed as "The soup, that presently is good, was deficient at the time I was in it" :)

Comment: For what it's worth, the modern/correct English equivalent is: "I was now well in the soup", where, as has been mentioned, ["in the soup"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20the%20soup) is an idiomatic phrase meaning that one is in serious trouble. Less idiomatically: "I was now in big trouble." More common, also idiomatic: "I was now in deep $#!^."

Comment: And a more idiomatic colloquial rendering would be: "I was in the soup now — [_but good!_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/but_good)" (I've always treated "but good" as an interpolation similar to "X — no kidding!" or at best an intensifier like "X, by God"; but the citations on Wiktionary come down surprisingly strongly on the side of "X but good" with no comma or dash or anything.) McPhee is simply leaving off the "but."

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is the voice of Capt Washburn speaking about his situation in 1946. He is an old sailor, with a strong dialect.  This isn't standard English.

The word "good" is an adverb in the sentence, with the meaning of "completely" or "to the utmost extent". But note that the adverbial use of "good" is considered to be a mistake in standard English.

Comment: *note that the adverbial use of "good" is considered to be a mistake in standard English.*  But also not that it's not particularly uncommon, though for me, "good" unadorned feels slightly awkward, whereas "pretty good" feels more natural.  If my car is in a ditch, I wouldn't think twice about saying "it's stuck pretty good".

Comment: I disagree that it is a mistake.  Good used as an adverb in the sense of "He did good on the test" is general considered a mistake.  But the usage in this example is perfectly idiomatic, although it's more common to see the "now" after the "good", as in "Oh, you're in it good now"

Comment: To add to Kevin's comment, "The boy did good" is a classic parody of a semi-literate football [soccer] manager describing how his star player performed.

Comment: @alephzero: That sounds like the "erudite" version to me! I'm more accustomed to hearing *The boy **done** good!* :)

Comment: I would say it means "well", not "completely". While "completely" works in this case, "well" covers the larger linguistic pattern, such as "How are you doing? / I'm doing good." Or, "I play chess good".

Comment: I think the meaning would've been clearer to native English speakers (though not to English learners) if it'd said “I was in the soup **but good**. The idiom “but good” is pretty well attested as meaning “to a high degree.” I feel like I see it most often in this sort of usage — as a wry pejorative to mean something like “this is a fine mess I've gotten myself into.”

Comment: As a life-long native English speaker from the U.S., I don't find anything wrong with the adverbial use of "good" in colloquial speech. People frequently break the "rules" when speaking. It ain't bad English... ;p

Comment: I'm not an English expert, but wouldn't a common example of "good" in this context be "the evil is gone **for good**"?

Comment: @Thomas— _for good_ is decidedly idiomatic unlike the adverbial use of _good_ in this case, which is dubious grammatically.

Comment: @User40475 Thank you for the clarification

Comment: @User40475 but still idiomatic in spoken English in the U.S.

Comment: Hello, in your answer you clarified the usage of the word "good", but can you explain the sentence as a whole? For example, what is "now" doing there? Is "in the soup" an idiom?

Answer (score 29):

"[In the soup](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20the%20soup#:%7E:text=informal%20%2B%20old%2Dfashioned,landed%20her%20in%20the%20soup.)" is an expression meaning "in trouble or a bad situation",  "good" here is an intensifier, trying to convey just how bad the situation is.

> informal + old-fashioned
> : in a bad situation : in trouble
> *That stunt landed her **in the soup***.

Comment: Upon reading the first part of your answer, I thought there was a comma missing, and "now good" meant he was no longer in trouble.

Comment: perhaps a modern twist, but my first association with "in the soup now" is to the proverbial frog who doesn't notice the slowly rising temperature in a pot of cold water set to cooking over a fire.  Like by the time the frog notices, it is too late, it's already part of the soup.